# Error occuring in Select Into Statement

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledbconnection, executenonquery

I have the following statement which has a syntax error in the 'From' clause, which has a couple of curly table names. The actual database names are the same as the tables, so they are all seperate.

I open a connection to the SealRegister mdb, which is empty (no tables yet), then ExecuteNonQuery on the statement. This I think should create the table SealRegister in the SealRegister.mdb.

```
sqlcommand = @"Select ""Plant"" As Geometry, A.Asset_ID, B.RoadID, A.AssetType, B.RoadName, B.SegmentNo, C.AadtCount, C.CommVehCnt " +
  @"Into [SealRegister] " +
    @"From [C:\AR\Plant\Accounting\2015].ARPlntPA_2015_07-2016_06+10yrs As A " +
      @"LEFT OUTER JOIN ([C:\AR\Lines\Accounting\2015].ARLnPA_2015_07-2016_06+10yrs As B " +
        @"LEFT OUTER JOIN [C:\AR\Lines\TEMP].ARLnX As C On B.Asset_ID = C.Asset_ID) On A.Parent_ID = B.Asset_ID " +
          @"WHERE AssetType = 'Wearing Course'";
```

What do I need to do to correct the syntax

[EDIT]

> connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=C:\AR\TEMP\SealRegister.mdb"

Comment: What is the error you have. Which driver are you using?

Comment: Popped the connection string above

Comment: Why using special operator characters as DB name? Probably you need to use square brackets to wrap those names, e.g.: `FROM [C:\AR\Plant\Accounting\2015].[ARPlntPA_2015_07-2016_06+10yrs] AS A`. The `-` and `+` sign each reserved for minus and plus operator in SQL, hence you can't use it directly as table name without brackets.

Comment: What is the error??On access If I remember it properly you also need to nest joins in brackets: `select a from (t1 inner join t2 on ...) t3 inner join t4 on ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
sqlcommand = @"Select ""Plant"" As Geometry, A.Asset_ID, B.RoadID, A.AssetType, B.RoadName, B.SegmentNo, C.AadtCount, C.CommVehCnt " +
  @"Into [SealRegister] " +
    @"From [C:\AR\Plant\Accounting\2015\ARPlntPA_2015_07-2016_06+10yrs].[ARPlntPA_2015_07-2016_06+10yrs] As A " +
      @"LEFT OUTER JOIN ([C:\AR\Lines\Accounting\2015\ARLnPA_2015_07-2016_06+10yrs].[ARLnPA_2015_07-2016_06+10yrs] As B " +
        @"LEFT OUTER JOIN [C:\AR\Lines\TEMP].ARLnX As C On B.Asset_ID = C.Asset_ID) On A.Parent_ID = B.Asset_ID " +
          @"WHERE AssetType = 'Wearing Course'";
```